# How to install a font without logging off or rebooting a PC?

Tags: c, windows, fonts

Is there a way or an API to install a font on the PC for every user, without logging off or restarting the PC?

Comment: Have you tried simply copying the file to the Fonts folder?

Comment: I think he means programmatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the MSDN document, [Font Installation and Deletion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for full details. In summary:

- Copy the font file to the fonts directory (`%windir%\fonts`).
- Call [`AddFontResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326%28VS.85%29.aspx) to ensure the font is immediately available.
- Broadcast the [`WM_FONTCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145211%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.

---

Thanks to @Alex K for cleaning this up and adding the fine detail.

Comment: You should also call addfontresource() in between those two steps to ensure its immediately available.

Comment: @Alex Added. I originally had included that but removed it because I thought it wasn't needed due to the WM_FONTCHANGE broadcast. Can you confirm that it is needed?

Comment: It's the call that actually updates the loaded font-table; 2nd bullet point @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx